# chosen select jQuery is not showing up in first loading

Tags: jquery, joomla, jquery-chosen

i have a joomla site.i am using a select dropdown.

```
<div class="dropdown">
                                                    <button id="all_suburbs" class="search-item-title btn dropdown-toggle search-by-btns" type="button">
                                                        <span class="search-item-icon iconrf-all-suburbs"></span>
                                                        <?php
                                      //======================================================================================================================================//                  
                                            $str_cities = "ALL SUBURBS OF CYPRUS";

                                            $str_cities = count($filter_suburbs_ids) ? count($filter_suburbs_ids).' Suburb'.(count($filter_suburbs_ids) > 1 ? 's' : '').' selected' : $str_cities;

                                            echo $str_cities;
                                     //======================================================================================================================================//                        
                                                        ?>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <ul class="all_suburbs dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="all_suburbs">
                                                        
                                                        <li>
                                                        <div id="filters_city_more" class="filter_options select_auto">
                                                            <div id="search_options_city_from" class="search_select_options" data-field-name="filter_a6suburb">
                                                               <select id="areas-select" multiple data-placeholder="Choose Suburbs..."  name="filter_a6suburb[]" onchange="setAreaFromPopup()" class="chosen-select">
                                                                    <?php foreach ($suburbs as $suburb) { ?>
                                                                        <option value="<?php echo $suburb->id; ?>" <?php echo (in_array($suburb->id, $filter_suburbs_ids)) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> class="option-city option-city-<?php echo $suburb->stateid; ?>" style="display:<?php echo ($filter_a6state == 0 || $filter_a6state == $suburb->stateid) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>"><?php echo $suburb->ezcity; ?></option>
                                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                                </select>

                                                                
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                      <span class="clear-btn" onclick="clearArea();"  title="Clear Suburbs Filter"><u>Clear</u></span> 
                                                     </ul>
                                                     
                                                </div>
```

and this is the jQuery code

```
jQuery('#all_suburbs').on('click', function (event) {           
            if(!jQuery('body').hasClass('home')){
                jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('open'); 
        jQuery("select.chosen-select").chosen(); 

            }
        });
```

The scripts using in the pages are

```
<?php
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addScript("/templates/op_rent/js/op/jquery.sumoselect.js", 'text/javascript');
$doc->addScript("/templates/op_rent/js/op/jquery.sumoselect.min.js", array(), array('async' => 'async'), 'text/javascript');


$doc->addScript(JURI::base() . "modules/mod_new_refine_search/assets/nouislider.min.js", array(), array('async' => 'async'), 'text/javascript');
$doc->addScript(JURI::base() . "modules/mod_new_refine_search/assets/jquery.smartmenus.js",'text/javascript');
$doc->addScript(JURI::base() . "modules/mod_new_refine_search/assets/jquery.smartmenus.min.js", array(), array('async' => 'async'), 'text/javascript');


$doc->addScript(JURI::base() . "media/jui/js/chosen.jquery.js",'text/javascript');

$doc->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . "media/jui/css/chosen.css");
```

?>

i am not getting the jQuerychosen select in the first loading.after that it is getting.can anybody help me in this.

Comment: Please always ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: i am seeking answer  for chosen jQuery ul class not showing.after that when we refresh we are getting it.how to sove it.

Comment: I realize that you are seeking a solution.  I am seeking questions for Joomla Stack Exchange -- a community full of people with particular expertise with the CMS.

Comment: ok.i had also added it there.can you help me with this